# Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0)

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I am using firebase for my android app and suddenly I am getting an error when I tried to run the app. Saturday it was working perfectly. I don't know how this error occurred and how to solve this. Please help me.

dependencies in my build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-android:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.8.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.tibolte:elasticdownload:1.0.+'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.6.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In my project level build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
    }
```

The Error I am getting:

> Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0).

Comment: add com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.1

Comment: not working in my case

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Make sure you have `google()` repository in project-level build.gradle before any others:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: As you suggested, I included `google()` repository. then an error showed and a link to update gradle version I updated that after that, I am getting a new error, `Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.0 ` Can you help me with that?

Comment: Look for `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.0` in app-level build.gradle, and try switching it to `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1`. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/

Answer (score 18):

Add this line in build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// Work around for onesignal-gradle-plugin compatibility
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

or

```
googleServices.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Comment: where should I add `com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true` this line? at the end of file?

Comment: below `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in build.gradle

Comment: Now, I am getting more errors! `Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0)`  and many more errors similar to this

Comment: ` compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'` use same version like 16.0.0 both

Comment: still getting same error `Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0)`

Comment: this solution worked...but what will be its side effects?

Comment: Actually, I don't know but if you dont use same version for com.google.gms then you have to add this @divaPrajapati09

Comment: i am using the same version in all dependency...also using your solution..still app crashes in oreo devices - @GautamSurani

Comment: can u share reason of crash in oreo devices?,like any crash report @divaPrajapati09

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/util/zzq; this is the error..i dont know whether it is related to this or not - @GautamSurani

Comment: are you sure you implemented latest version of `com.google.android.gms` @divaPrajapati09

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183549/discussion-between-gautam-surani-and-divaprajapati09).

Comment: googleServices.disableVersionCheck = true , I added this line and the Error gone , but what it does ? .. can you please explain

Comment: I find it very strange... with this it works... but I'm afraid what the side effects are/will be 

Answer (score 10):

I encountered the same issue after updating. Try to verify if you installed the latest Build Tool and Google Repository versions.

[image]

Also, verify the **Project's `build.gradle`** that you're using `google()` and the **build tool version**. After checking the `build.gradle`, try to re-sync, clean, and re-build your project.

If needed, try to update to the latest version of your project's dependencies.

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    }
    // ...
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But, I found my answer.

Comment: The latest Google Play services SDK components are no long published via the SDK Manager tool from the screenshot. Use the `google()` repository instead.

Answer (score 5):

in my case i just update `Andorid SDK Platform-Tools` previous was 28.0.0 when i updated it to 28.0.1 problem fix!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Answer (score 4):

All of sudden with out any changes in my project I was getting below error.

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:[15.0.0, 16.0.0).

In project level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools'
        }
    }
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
```

and

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/' }
    }
}
```

with above settings I had no luck.

Below is what worked for me
I found that the problem is with onesignal

I added exclude clause to dependency:

```
implementation ('com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.5') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
```

then added the missing dependencies manually.
After adding exclude clause I got Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:[10.2.1, 12.1.0). If you find any other missing dependencies just do as I did below.

In the module level build.gradle I replaced

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0' with
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
```

and finally Build completed successfully. I wasted almost 5 hours on this. Hope this helps some one.

Answer (score 3):

In my case everything was working fine, but suddenly I encountered this problem in the next "run action"!
Anyway, the problem is solved by updating `com.google.gms:google-services` in the **project build.gradle** file to **its latest version** as the below :

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
    }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Also, make sure that:
- You are not in **offline mode**.
- And if you are using **Http Proxy**, you can connect to the google repository.

Note (in the above sample):
**Android Studio** : 3.4.2
**compileSdkVersion** 28
**targetSdkVersion** 28

Answer (score 2):

## Build -> Clean Project

was enough in my special case (with **gms:`v15.0.1`** and **firebase:`v16.0.1`**).

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue with this build.gradle [Proyect]

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**OPTION 1:**

**Follow the below instruction to resolve it.**

> Project-level build.gradle

**use**

```
maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
```

**instead of**

```
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

**OPTION 2:**

**Follow the below steps to resolve it.**

**Step1:**

> Project-level build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' // google-services plugin
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } // For Ucrop
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } // Google's Maven repository - FCM
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/azeesoft/maven'
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Step2:**

> App-level build.gradle

I have update One Signal version.

**use**

```
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.11.1'
```

**instead of**

```
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.9'
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing

```
implementation('com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.15.1')
```

with

```
  implementation('com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.15.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'customtabs'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
```

solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me. In project-level Gradle file use the following order:

```java
repositories {
    google()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    jcenter()
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons would be

1. Internet not connected/work Offline not enabled from AndroidStudio Preference
2. Cached versions of dependancy not exists
3. Proxy enabled
4. Google Play Service Temporarily Unavailable

Solution :

Along with the above answers don't forget to add  `mavenLocal()` inside project level `build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
                   ......
                   ......

                   mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

This helps to access cached dependencies when Service Temporarily Unavailable

Comment: mavenlocal has nothing to do with cached dependencies

Answer (score 1):

go to build.gradle in android directory , insert

```
maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
```

in top position of repositories of allprojects same this :

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } //<<--Insert this above google()
    google()
```

Answer (score 0):

i deleted every firebase plugin like:

1. [firebase_core](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core)
2. [cloud_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore)
3. [firebase_dynamic_links](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links)
4. [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging)
5. [firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth)

from `pubspec.yaml`

and run `pub get` and `flutter run`

add packages again

run `pub get` and `flutter run` again

worked for me.

if not fixed, try packages one by one

Answer (score 0):

i was facing this error
failed to resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-image-label-model:20.1.0
**solution**
just remove the

> com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-image-label-model:20.1.0

from the gradle.build (app)