# Execution failed for task ':location:generateDebugRFile'. Flutter Build failed

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, google-play-services

I tried running my app on android emulator for the first time and this error showed up
Execution failed for task ':location:generateDebugRFile'.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':location:generateDebugRFile'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':location:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16..
     Required by:
         project :location

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

my app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// START: FlutterFire Configuration
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// END: FlutterFire Configuration
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.fun"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// Work around for onesignal-gradle-plugin compatibility
googleServices.disableVersionCheck = true
```

My android/build.grade

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        // START: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        // END: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

my flutter doctor summary

```
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.71.0)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

I am just trying to launch the app on an android emulator so It can create a debug.keystore file, I have tried many options from other facing kind of the simillar problem

Comment: How you tried upgrading Flutter? and would be much appreciated if you could put the full error message.

Comment: @RezaAslejeddian I added the entire error and my flutter doctor, and my flutter is up to date

Comment: Aha, there are some solutions in here, I recommend checking them out.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50791632/could-not-find-any-version-that-matches-com-google-android-gmsplay-services-bas

Comment: @RezaAslejeddian I did try these, but still won't work

Comment: OK, then try these:
Find caches folder of gradle in your system for example on mac is :/Users/USER/.gradle/caches and delete it.
Make sure you have good internet which is allowed to download from gradle repositories(You are not banned).
Run the project & Build apk

Comment: I tried this it did not work

Comment: I have the same problem here.. did you find the solution for this issue?